# System Lockup on X399

Tags: system-installation, lockup

I just finished an X399 build and tried to install Ubuntu 18.04, but about 20 seconds into the install it locks up. I tried the "try Ubuntu" and the same thing occurs even if you do nothing.

Running top shows no abnormal usage - it just locks up. I have to hold power as it never recovers even overnight. I have *IOMMU*, *Secure Boot* and *Fast Boot* disabled in UEFI/BIOS.

I Was wondering if anyone had ran into this or have any solutions.